# AADSTS50011:The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, react-functional-component

I have configured Active directory login for React application. I'm getting this error. I have registered my application in azure also.

Code written in authconfig.js file:

[image: cpde]]

Comment: Please do not post images of code/errors/data. Instead post the code/errors/data as text in a code block. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could see you've configured RedirectURI with "https://localhost:4200" from authconfig.js so wondering do you have same URL configured as Redirect URI in azure AD for registered application? This value must match exactly lets say if your code configured "http://localhost:4200" but in Azure AD you have replyurl as "http://localhost:4200" (without "S") then above error is expected.

[image]

More detail refer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/error-code-aadsts50011-reply-url-mismatch